# Under what conditions would we see fungi dominating the surface of a planet?

Tags: science-based, biology

Fungi are generally decomposers, but I've heard of fungi which can digest rock, and that such fungi were on land before plants and that their rock-digestion is what made the soil livable for plants.

I'm pretty sure these fungi were also tiny. Is there any mineral that could be present in the ground that would cause the fungi to grow large and spread all over the place? Perhaps accompanied by lichen? What other conditions would encourage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

Here on Earth, in forests for example, you often find fungi on trees facing north or south ( depending on your hemisphere ) because that's where  they'll get the least light exposure.

Most fungi like **humidity and darkness.**

This doesn't mean that your planet can't have rock-eating fungi, it means it can't be covered in them.